# SQL Server : compare 2 data loads and then stamp the ones with a delta

Tags: sql-server, exists

The following problem keeps me occupied. Regarding finding and stamping delta's.

I have 2 data loads of exactly the same 100 rows in the `dbo.persoon` table, marked with load1 and load2 respectively. I have made 3 column changes in those 200 records to make sure that there are delta's. If I run the `select...except...select` part then these delta's will show up.

Next I want to mark the rows for these delta's by using the update statement. However when I run the update code there will be a message that 200 rows are effected. Does anyone know how to fix this and only update the rows with delta's?

```
update dbo.persoon
set Marking_Field='10'
where exists 
    (select [ID_person],[NM_firstname] from dbo.persoon where load_date='load1'
     except
     select [ID_person],[NM_firstname] from dbo.persoon where load_date='load2')
```

Comment: Sounds like a good case for using MERGE

Comment: @Ghost MERGE is for upserts, in this case the OP only wants to update the correct rows. A correct JOIN would do the job.

Comment: @mgo your query will update every row in `person` if the subquery contains any rows. Since there is on connection between UPDATE's `person` and the subquery, that means that all rows will be updated

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, thanks for your comments. How can your suggestion be added to the code? I tried some variants but they do not seem to give the correct results.

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, hope you have time to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Why wont this work...

```
with cte
as
(
select [ID_person],[NM_firstname] from dbo.persoon where load_date='load1'
     except
     select [ID_person],[NM_firstname] from dbo.persoon where load_date='load2'
)
update cte
set Marking_Field='10'
```

Comment: Thanks will try asap

Comment: tried it, but it still updates all 200 rows. So it could be that Panagiotis is correct.